# JavaScript - Get only a part of the string after a particular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following:

```
var string = 'https://sub.example.com/dir/ https://sub.example.com/dir/v2.5/'
var hostname = 'sub.example.com';
var hostname_match = hostname.replace(/\./g, '\\.');

string.replace(new RegExp('https\:\/\/'+hostname_match+'\/(.*)', 'g'), '/$1');
```

What I want is to get the following :

```
/dir/ /dir/v2.5/
```

Comment: Try `string.replace(new RegExp('https://'+hostname_match+'/(\\S*)', 'g'), '/$1')`

Comment: What I want is to get whatever after the : sub.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace the `http:// + hostname`:

```js
var string = 'https://sub.example.com/dir/ https://sub.example.com/dir/v2.5/'
var hostname = 'sub.example.com';

let urls = string.split(' ')
.map(u => u.replace('https://'+hostname, ''))

console.log(urls)

// if you want a space-separated string:
console.log(urls.join(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
new RegExp('https://'+hostname_match+'/(\\S*)', 'g')
```

Here, `.*` is replaced with `\S*` matching zero or more non-whitespace characters.

See JS demo:

```js
var string = 'https://sub.example.com/dir/ https://sub.example.com/dir/v2.5/'
var hostname = 'sub.example.com';
var hostname_match = hostname.replace(/\./g, '\\.');
console.log(
  string.replace(new RegExp('https://'+hostname_match+'/(\\S*)', 'g'), '/$1')
);
```

Note that you do not need to escape forward slashes in the constructor notation, as `/` is not a special regex metacharacter. The colon does not have to be escaped in any regex contexts.